# onActivityCreated() is deprecated and I think it's causing my save contact feature to not work, but no idea how to fix it

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have been working on an Android app for a project and have to make a communications button that basically just works as a contacts app. So I followed a tutorial on how to make it, but he uses some deprecated libraries, including a lot of lifecycle. To make the "save contact" button work on the app, he did an ovverride on the "onActivityCreated" function. However, onActivityCreated was deprecated and I've been looking for ways to fix it but to no avail.

The code below is my AddContactDialogFragment.kt class, where I am trying to actually make the addcontact happen, so the issue is most likely in there. You can see the commented out override of "onViewCreated" which I tried after seeing onActivityCreated is deprecated.

```
package com.example.mavhealth.ui

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.mavhealth.R
import com.example.mavhealth.data.Contact
import com.example.mavhealth.databinding.FragmentAddContactDialogBinding
import androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver

class AddContactDialogFragment : DialogFragment(), DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    private var _binding: FragmentAddContactDialogBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var viewModel: ContactViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super<DialogFragment>.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_MinWidth)
        activity?.lifecycle?.removeObserver(this)

        viewModel.result.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
            val message = if (it == null) {
                getString(R.string.added_contact)
            }else{
                getString(R.string.error, it.message)
            }
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            dismiss()
        })
        binding.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener {
            val fullName = binding.editTextFullName.text.toString().trim()
            val contactNumber = binding.editTextContact.toString().trim()
            if(fullName.isEmpty())
            {
                binding.editTextFullName.error = "This is a required field"
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            if(contactNumber.isEmpty())
            {
                binding.editTextContact.error = "This is a required field"
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            val contact = Contact()
            contact.name = fullName
            contact.number = contactNumber
            viewModel.addContact(contact)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
    {
        _binding = FragmentAddContactDialogBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[ContactViewModel::class.java]
        return binding.root
    }
/*
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.result.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
            val message = if (it == null) {
                getString(R.string.added_contact)
            }else{
                getString(R.string.error, it.message)
            }
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            dismiss()
        })
        binding.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener {
            val fullName = binding.editTextFullName.text.toString().trim()
            val contactNumber = binding.editTextContact.toString().trim()
            if(fullName.isEmpty())
            {
                binding.editTextFullName.error = "This is a required field"
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            if(contactNumber.isEmpty())
            {
                binding.editTextContact.error = "This is a required field"
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            val contact = Contact()
            contact.name = fullName
            contact.number = contactNumber
            viewModel.addContact(contact)
        }
    }
*/

    override fun onAttach(context: Context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context)
        activity?.lifecycle?.addObserver(this)
    }

}
```

This code block is my ContactViewModel.kt class, where I do have a addContact function, so this could also be where things are going wrong.

```
package com.example.mavhealth.ui

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.example.mavhealth.data.Contact
import com.example.mavhealth.data.NODE_CONTACTS
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase

class ContactViewModel: ViewModel()
{
    private val dbContacts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(NODE_CONTACTS)
    private val _result = MutableLiveData<Exception?>()
    val result: LiveData<Exception?> get() = _result
    fun addContact(contact: Contact)
    {
        contact.id = dbContacts.push().key
        dbContacts.child(contact.id!!).setValue(contact).addOnCompleteListener{
            if(it.isSuccessful)
            {
                _result.value = null
            }
            else
            {
                _result.value = it.exception
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image: For reference, here is the exception I get when I click the "save contact" button]

I have tried swapping the "onActivityCreated" override to "onViewCreated", but that didn't work. Either the override didn't work, or my code to make the save contact work is not correct. Afterwards, I saw some posts saying to override "onCreate" and "onAttach", but when I did that, not only did the save contact not work, but clicking save contact now crashed my app. I have no idea if I'm doing it incorrectly, or if the correct solution is completely passing me, but I would appreciate any help.

Update 1: I tried initializing viewmodel with the commented out onViewCreated code and while it did not crash, the save contact still did not work. This has me wondering if I set up my firebase incorrectly in that it can't read/write.

Comment: There is almost never a reason to override `onAttach` or `onCreate`. Your code in `onActivityCreated` should be moved to `onViewCreated`, but it should still work even though it's deprecated. What exactly is the failure you see if you have the code in `onViewCreated`? You don't need to add an observer of the Activity lifecycle. The Fragment already has its own lifecycle functions.

Comment: Review the [Fragment Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle). The error is clear - you are using the `ViewModel` in `onCreate` before it's initialized. Initialize it first.

Comment: @Tenfour04 So when just moving my code from "onActivityCreated" to "onViewCreated", my "save contact" button doesn't work, doesn't cause a crash or anything weird. I guess that could just mean my code isn't doing it correct if it should work even if it isn't deprecated, I just don't see what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

viewmodel is not initialized.
In the your code, the viewmodel is initialized in onCreatedView, but an error occurs because onCreate operates first in the life cycle.
I think it would be better to create it by default because no additional options are applied when creating the viewmodel.

```kotlin
private val viewModel: ContactViewModel by viewModels()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewModel.result.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
    val message = if (it == null) {
        getString(R.string.added_contact)
    }else{
        getString(R.string.error, it.message)
    }
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    dismiss()
})
```

at here,viewLifecycleOwner must be initialized